# Clicking all buttons using console

Tags: javascript, jquery, console

I have html element of the form:

```
<div class="hello world button">hello world</div>
```

which appears 50 times.

I want to click all 50 of them using jquery/chrome console but I'm not being able to. I have tried using

```
('.hello world button').click()
```

However, console just returns an empty array.

Comment: add $ before ('.hello world button').click()

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. You're missing the `$`.
2. Your buttons have three separate classes on them. The CSS selector to match elements with all three classes is `.hello.world.button` not `.hello world button`

So:

```
$(".hello.world.button").click();
```

That will click the buttons. Whether what they **do** will work will depend a lot on what they do.

Answer (score 0):

The way you are using a selector is incorrect. Since `$('hello world button')` will look for class `world` in the child tags of the div with class `hello` and not in the div itself and so on. You need a selector like `$('.hello.world.button')` that will match for all the three clasess for the same `div` . Plus you are missing a `$` sign which I assume is a typo and is not in your actual code.

```js
$(function() {
  $('.hello.world.button').click(function() {
    console.log('clicked');
  });
  
  $('.hello.world.button').trigger('click');
})
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="hello world button">hello world</div>
<div class="hello world button">hello world</div>
<div class="hello world button">hello world</div><div class="hello world button">hello world</div><div class="hello world button">hello world</div>
<div class="hello world button">hello world</div><div class="hello world button">hello world</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Class_selectors

> In an HTML document, CSS class selectors match an element based on the
>   contents of the element's class attribute. The class attribute is
>   defined as a space-separated list of items, and one of those items
>   must match exactly the class name given in the selector.

Your selector class is wrong ( that mean you have 3 classes on the div tag)

To fix this you can add `_` between the words

```
<div class="hello_world_button">hello world</div>
```

and in js

```
$('.hello_world_button').click()
```

Answer (score 0):

Use only one class for access any event.
Try This

```
$('.button').click();
or
$('.hello').click();
or
$('.world').click();
```